# How to set a value to some of the coefficients in glmfit

Tags: regression, generalized-linear-model, modeling, poisson-regression, regression-coefficients

want to use GLM to model the binary data. I have 3 different covariates, X1, X2 and X3. X1 is estimated with 14 basis functions and X2 and X3 are estimated with 10 basis functions. Hence I have 14+10+10=34 basis functions. When I run GLM I will get 35 coefficients (one extra is for the constant term). I want to be able to give an initial value to some of these coefficient and not allow GLM to change it, that is, I want GLM to estimate the remaining coefficients. Is there anyway to do this with glmfit or some other functions?

Comment: This is called *offsetting*.

Comment: Can you explain it a little more. Just to be clear, I don't not want some of those coefficients change through GLM. I want GLM gives me exactly the same value for those coefficients that I set value for, but it can change the value of the other coefficients.

Comment: Yup, explained below.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this is called offsetting.  When using an offset, you estimate a regression model of the form:

$$y_i = \beta_0 + \beta_1 x_{i1} + \cdots + \beta_k x_{ik} + o_{i} + \epsilon $$

where $o_i$ is a constant (for each observation), called the **offset**.

Suppose you want to set the parameters $\beta_1, \beta_2, \ldots, \beta_r$ to fixed values.  Then you would simply compute the constant

$$ o_i = \beta_0 + \beta_1 x_{i1} + \cdots + \beta_r x_{ir} $$

for each data point, and use this as an offset in a regression model including all of the *other* parameters.

In R, the `glm` function [supports offsets](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/stats/versions/3.4.1/topics/glm):

> offset: this can be used to specify an a priori known component to be included in the linear predictor during fitting. This should be NULL or a numeric vector of length equal to the number of cases. One or more offset terms can be included in the formula instead or as well, and if more than one is specified their sum is used. See `model.offset`.

Comment: Wow, that's great. This is exactly what I needed. I found that in Matlab glmfit function also allows to have a parameter called 'offset'. Thanks for the complete explanation.